# Visual form inheritance in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm newbie in Qt. I came from Delphi IDE. I can't find solution to inherit from form. For example: In Delphi project I had own `TBaseForm` class with controls created using designer (`.dfm`-file, similar to `.ui` in Qt). When create new form, I could select form from project and then new form had all controls from base form. Furthermore, changing controls in base form had affects in all descendants in real time. Can I do something similar in Qt Creator?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like you say, manually.

For example:

1. Add new form class inherited from `QWidget` (name it `BaseForm`).
2. Add new form class inherited from `QWidget` (name it `ChildForm`).
3. In `childform.h/cpp` manually change inheritance from `QWidget` to `BaseForm`.

In design time, you can't see changes of child when you change parent. But, when execute it, you'll see it.